# parsing xml into an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have an xml file that I have been given and need to parse it with php and display the values. I want to put this xml data into an array where I can easily select the data I need.

The data is in the format:

```
<person id="2">
    <child>
        <name>kim</name>
        <born>1990</born>
    </child>
</person>
<person id="2">
    <parent>
        <name>emma</name>
        <born>1950</born>
    </parent>
</person>
```

so I first have a loop scanning through the data to see if parent of child. If parent I want to make an array of all the parents and then the children.

So then I can have a table and just iterate through all the parent names, their birth dates etc and a seperate one for children.

```
foreach($plannerXML->children() as $child){

    if ($child->count()>0) {
        foreach($child as $childs)
        {
            if ($childs->getName()=="parent") {
                if ($childs->count()>0) {
                    foreach($childs as $childss){



                        $parent=array($childss->getName()=>$childss
                        );

                    };
                }
            } else if ($childs->getName()=="child") {

            }
        };
    };
};
```

so I then have an array which has the data but how can I then echo this out to show the name and the related birthdate?

At the moment if I put it in a loop I get all of the names , all of the dates etc ..

Comment: Why `;` is after `}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) website, you can do a conversion from xml to array code like:

```
<?php
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
?>
```

---

For your situation, use the [example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php).